# Definition of Chrome App/Extension/Legacy

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

From what I understand each Chrome App/Extension/Legacy is defined by attributes in its `manifest.json`, those attributes being the following:

Chrome App:

A Chrome App will have the following in its `mainfest.json`:

```js
"app": 
{
    "background": 
    {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

`background.js` calls the chrome code ***`chrome.app.window.create`*** which will open a new standalone application.

Chrome Extension:

A Chrome Extension will have the following in its `mainfest.json`:

```js
"browser_action": 
{
    "default_popup": "index.html"
}
```

This will add an extension to Chrome. Extensions are addons to the Chrome browser.

Chrome Legacy:

```js
"app":
{
    "launch":
    {
         "local_path": "index.html"
    }
}
```

This is like a web application that is opened in a new tab in Chrome.

Can you please confirm that this is correct.

Comment: Your question is quite cluttered and unclear. 1) Maybe cut the background information. Is it important? 2) Cut out the additional questions you have. Looks like you have something that you can formulate as a separate question about legacy apps. Do that: make a separate question. 3) Spend time formatting the question. It will be easier to read. See [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Oh, and suggestion: **delete** your question, edit it, then undelete. This will protect you from downvotes while you get it in shape. See also [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [**extension**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) does not have to have a browser action, or indeed any visible UI. Anything that does not have an `app` section in the manifest is an extension.

It is used for any kind of functionality that interacts with normal browsing. See [available APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index).

---

A [**legacy packaged app**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/apps) is a now-deprecated type of apps that open in a browser tab but use local components and have access to Chrome API.

They are, indeed, identified by having `app.launch.local_path` key in the manifest.

Quoting the docs:

> Legacy packaged apps are discontinued, and Chrome will stop loading them in June 2015

Additionally, Chrome Web Store [no longer accepts legacy apps](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/06/migrate-your-legacy-packaged-apps-to.html).

---

A [**hosted app**](https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide) is, essentially, a small piece of metadata that mostly acts like a convenient shortcut to a website.

It is defined by having a `app.launch.web_url` key. As you can infer, they appeared at the same time as legacy packaged apps.

It's a useful app type if you already have a web app but want some presence in the Chrome Web Store. However, users are frequently angry at such apps for being "just a link to a website".

---

A [**Chrome App**](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) (also "packaged app" to differentiate from the hosted ones, but this term is not recommended, since it was used for legacy apps) is a self-contained HTML5 application that opens UI separate from the browser. It's the "new" apps paradigm.

It is defined by having an `app.background` key. That defines an event page that [regulates the lifecycle](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_lifecycle) of the app.

Google for a long time had a stance that Chrome Apps are as independent from the browser as possible, and as such [their API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index) does not, for the most part, allow interaction with the browser. This standpoint is slowly eroding<sup>[[citation needed]](http://xkcd.com/285/)</sup>, though.

---

Google has a [nice (if slightly outdated) flowchart](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/choosing) to decide which type of app/extension you need for your functionality:

[image: Google, CC-By-3.0]

Also, there is an [in-depth explanation of differences](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/apps_vs_extensions).